# Is there a dimension formula for modular forms of weight $1$ for any congruence subgroup?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

If $M_1(\Gamma )$ denotes the vector space of modular forms of weight $1$ for $\Gamma$, is there any formula  for $\text{dim}(M_1(\Gamma ))$?

Comment: Theorem 3.6.1 in Diamond and Shurman's book gives a partial answer. Namely, if $\varepsilon_{\infty}^{\text{reg}}$ denotes the number of regular cusps and $g$ is the genus of $X(\Gamma)$, then $\dim(M_1(\Gamma))=\varepsilon_{\infty}^{\text{reg}}/2$ if $\varepsilon_{\infty}^{\text{reg}}>2g-2$ and $\dim(M_1(\Gamma))\geq\varepsilon_{\infty}^{\text{reg}}/2$ otherwise. However, I'm not familiar with any result beyond this.

Comment: Nope. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61263/modular-forms-of-weight-one